# Update Puppet agents with last manifests changes automatically

Tags: centos, puppet

I have a Puppet server with 10 agents on CentOS 6.6. To update agents with last manifests changes I use this command on agents:

```
puppet agent --no-daemonize --onetime --verbose
```

So when I make a change in puppet server I need to access all agents and run this commands. I want to know if there is a command which I can run in Puppet server to update all agents with last manifests changes.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Before there was "puppet kick" https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/3.4.2/man/kick.html

I believe that it has been deprecated reading the following webpage:

- https://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/15735
- https://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/15427
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/puppet-users/RpNJmOHIPmA

A solution for this need without deprecated tool is mcollective using the following plugin:

http://projects.puppetlabs.com/projects/mcollective-plugins/wiki/AgentPuppetd